# Ring structure for $K^{-1}$?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology

My questions are

1. whether there exists a product structure for $K^{-1}(X)$? Here $K^{-1}$ is the odd topological $K$-group, and $X$ is a compact space (or a manifold), say.
2. If such a ring structure exists then how to multiply two elements? For example, if we take $K^{-1}(X):=[X, GL(\mathbb{C})]$, where $GL(\mathbb{C})$ is the infinite general linear group, then for $f, g\in K^{-1}(X)$, I could have guessed that the product structure is given by $f\otimes g$, and I would think of it as the tensor product of two matrices of finite but not equal size.
3. Moreover, if a ring structure for $K^{-1}$ really exists, may you provide me a reference?

I know $K^0(X)$ is a ring and $K^0(X)\oplus K^{-1}(X)$ is a ring. But I don't know whether $K^{-1}(X)$ along is a ring or not.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The product of two elements of $K^{-1}(X)$ belongs to $K^{-2}(X)$ which is identified with $K^0(X)$ via the Bott periodicity. Thus $K^{-1}(X)$ is not a ring.

Comment: You might try to use the suspension isomorphism $\tilde K^{-1}(X)\cong\tilde K(\Sigma X)$...

Comment: @semyonalesker:  Your comment does not prove that there is no natural ring structure on $K^{-1}$.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg: You are right. But I hoped that it does prove that there is no KNOWN canonical ring structure.

Comment: @Steven Landsburg and semyon alesker: Actually my question was motivated by the Chern character. We know $ch:K^0(X)\to H^{even}(X; \mathbb{Q})$ is a ring homomorphism. However, the odd Chern character is only a group homomorphism. Even a ring structure of $K^{-1}$ exists, I don't think the odd Chern character would be a ring homomorphism unless we define/find a suitable ring structure on $H^{odd}(X; \mathbb{Q})$. I am not very satisfied that the odd Chern character is only a group homomorphism.

Comment: I believe a relevant question to study in connection to the last comment is - what kind of module is $K^{odd}$ over $K^{even}$ and $H^{odd}$ over $H^{even}$... (Note that they are moreover equipped with kind of scalar products $()^{odd}\otimes_{()^{even}}()^{odd}\to()^{even})$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე In your first comment you suggest to consider the ring structure coming from $\tilde K(\Sigma X)$. I just want to point out that any cup product on a suspension is trivial, no matter in which extraordinary multiplicative cohomology theory you work. On the other hand, suggestion 2 in the question seems to make sense and might actually produce a ring.

Comment: @SebastianGoette Hands up - nothing to say :D